# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

i get the following error, using the jwt-simple lib:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at module.exports (C:\my_application\services\mylist.js:5:40)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at C:\my_application\api.js:39:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at logger (C:\my_application\node_modules\morgan\index.js:144:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\my_application\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

and here is mylist.js file:

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');


module.exports = function (req, res) {
  var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  var payload = jwt.decode(token, "shhh..");
  if(!payload.sub) {
    res.status(401).send({
      message: 'Authentication failed'
    });
  }
  if(!req.headers.authorization){
    return res.status(401).send({
      message: 'You are not authorized'
    });
  }
  res.json(mylist);
};

var mylist = [
  'Proj 1',
  'Proj 2',
  'Proj 3',
  'Proj 4'
];
```

i am trying to see if the user is authorized to access the mylist resource on frontend. 
does anyone have any idea?

Comment: you need to be defensive here: `req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: @DanielA.White How would that help if `split` itself is not defined?

Comment: Like the error message tells you quite clearly, `req.headers.authorization` is undefined, so you can't `split` it.

Comment: `split` is defined on a string, but the property is undefined.

Comment: just move `var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];` after `if(!req.headers.authorization){`

Comment: @jcubic i did, but it says, `Error: No token supplied`

Comment: the whole payload code need to be after the token.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you assume it's a string, even if you don't know if there really is a string there.
You should add some error checking first

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {
  if (typeof req.headers.authorization !== 'string') {
    res.sendStatus(400);
    return;
  }

  var tokens = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');

  if (tokens.length < 2) {
    res.sendStatus(400);
    return;
  }

  var token = tokens[1];

  var payload = jwt.decode(token, "shhh..");
  if(!payload.sub) {
    res.status(401).send({
      message: 'Authentication failed'
    });
  }
  ...
};
```

**Edit:** But why exactly do you want the second token and not the first?

Comment: i need second part because i have `Bearer ' + token` in my authinterceptor.